# Regular Expression, Creating an alarm to check for a string that appears less than 5 times.

Tags: regex

I think it is going to be harder to explain this than to get a solution.  I am using sitescope to monitor a webpage.  I need to check the webpage for the string Div Class='proxy'.  We are using a software that automatically checks a group of computers.  It then creates a dashboard with Each computer and its status. We always have 5 computers in this group.  We want an alarm that goes off when a computer disappears.  The sitescope monitor uses regex to search for content on the page.  There is no other identify marks we can search for except for div class='proxy' which is created for each computer.   Of course in the source code the  5 div classes are not sequential so (div class='proxy'){5} does not return a happy resonpse. 
what we want.

```
If div class='proxy' appears 5 times in the document return true
if div class='proxy' less than 5 times in the document return false
```

Like I said the hard part was going to be explaning the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like: `(div class='proxy'.?){5}`?

Comment: Yes....except for the last ?  I'll try that tomorrow and let u know how that goes.